# How to check if an array index exist?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check whether an array index exist in TypeScript, by the following way (Just for example):

```
var someArray = [];

// Fill the array with data

if ("index" in someArray) {
   // Do something
}
```

However, i'm getting the following compilation error:

> The in operator requires the left operand to be of type Any or the
>   String primitive type, and the right operand to be of type Any or an
>   object type

Anybody knows why is that? as far as I know, what I'm trying to do is completely legal by JS.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be using an object, not an array.

Comment: Is "index" a string or an actual numeric index?

Comment: a string.
I guess that I'll do as SLaks said, i thought that typescript arrays can be used a associative arrays as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the comments indicated, you're mixing up arrays and objects. An array can be accessed by numerical indices, while an object can be accessed by string keys. Example:

```
var someObject = {"someKey":"Some value in object"};

if ("someKey" in someObject) {
    //do stuff with someObject["someKey"]
}

var someArray = ["Some entry in array"];

if (someArray.indexOf("Some entry in array") > -1) {
    //do stuff with array
}
```

Comment: Is there a opposite of the operator in ?

Comment: logical, if (!("someKey" in someObject))

Answer (score 11):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9VEp/)**

Use `hasOwnProperty` like this:

```
var a = [];
if( a.hasOwnProperty("index") ){
 /* do something */  
}
```

Comment: Maybe better use hasOwnProperty as `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, 'index')` neat explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12017703/3848267)

Comment: It's true, there are ways that the hasOwnProperty could have been abused. If you are making some sort of largely portable library, it may make sense to cover all bases like that. In general though, this works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

One line validation. The simplest way.

```
if(!!currentData[index]){
  // do something
}
```

Outputs

```
var testArray = ["a","b","c"]

testArray[5]; //output => undefined
testArray[1]; //output => "b"

!!testArray[5]; //output => false
!!testArray[1]; //output => true
```

Comment: `!!` is redundant here. Also, consider the arrays `[0, 1, 2]` and `[false, false]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the findindex method :

```
var someArray = [];

if( someArray.findIndex(x => x === "index") >= 0) {
    // foud someArray element equals to "index"
}
```

Comment: here x is nothing but whole object inside a array. So how this would help?