# Object.getOwnPropertyNames() vs Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

Both of these obviously do similar things but my question is why is one on the prototype and one on the Object?

For example, both of these called differently. Is there a logical reason why this is the case?

```
var o = {name: "value"}

o.hasOwnProperty("name") //true

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o); //name 
//Couldn't the above have been coded so we can run o.getOwnPropertNames();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Similar by having to do with property names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with adding these methods to the prototype is taht they are prone to getting overloaded.

```
var o = {};
o.getOwnPropertyNames = 17;
//What now?
```

In fact, you would often see people doing

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, propname);
```

in order to avoid [the overloading issue with hasOwnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12017693/1048572).

Comment: So then why is `hasOwnProperty` on the prototype?

Comment: For no good reason to be honest. Its just that we can't "fix" it now without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Really? I'll try to control my urge to downvote for a bit though.

Comment: @KingKongFrog: Because that's how it was designed at first, and had to stay for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Actually it does seems that no new object methods where introduced since ES3.