# ie javascript for in loop vs chrome for in loop

Tags: javascript

```
var arr=["test"]; for(var e in arr) console.log(e);
```

in IE11's  console it outputs:

0 contains remove clear add addAll(all properties)

and in chrome's console only outputs `0`, which is expected.

how to fix it in IE? I know I can use `for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)` to solve it.
but I just wonder why IE outputs all the properties.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: @ssube questions are duplicates, not answers. Even if the _answer_ is the same, only close a duplicate if the _question_ is the same.

Comment: @MattBall Fixed my comment phrasing. The question is phrased differently, but is the same issue. Not quite sure if it's a dupe or not, right on the edge.

Comment: If you add properties via Object.defineProperty you can prevent them from being enumerated in the list. IE is doing it right.

Comment: Most likely the page has created some polyfills for non-existing properties in IE. `for..in` is expected to iterate the properties in the prototype chain too. If Chrome doesn't iterate them (which I doubt), it would clearly be a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

using IE11 and looks ok to me

[image]

if you want more control use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.It accepts a callback which have three parameters.They are element,their index and the array itself.Try

```
var arr=["test",'ball'];arr.forEach(function(element,index){
   console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hasOwnProperty` method.

Example:

```javascript
var arr = ["test"];
for (var e in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Good explanation on why this is necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12017703/1387396

Details on the `hasOwnProperty` method and its use in `for .. in` loops:  [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Example:_Itarate_over_properties_not_considering_inherited_properties)