# Can you think of a way to call hasOwnProperty on an object that has its own property by that name?

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
let map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};

console.log(map.hasOwnProperty("one"));//error map.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

The above code should **return true**. How to achieve this?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604063/what-is-the-appropriate-recommended-way-to-use-hasownproperty

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways:

1. `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, "one")`.
2. The brand-new [`Object.hasOwn(map, "one")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), if your target environments support it (it's easily polyfilled if not), which was added precisely because of this issue.

Example:

```js
let map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};

console.log(
    "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call:", 
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, "one")
);
if (Object.hasOwn) {
    console.log("Object.hasOwn:", Object.hasOwn(map, "one"));
} else {
    console.log("Object.hasOwn not supported in this environment yet");
}
```

There are also some methods on [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) that are useful for these things, such as [`Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) (`Object` has a similar method), which would return an object that had `value: true` on it (because `one` is a data property, not an accessor property).

---

Note that, unfortunately, even these static methods can be replaced, so at some point you just have to trust that the environment isn't actively set up to lie to you. :-) For what it's worth, here's an example of a compromised environment:

```js
let map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};

console.log("Setting up the lies");
const originalHasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
const originalHasOwn = Object.hasOwn;

Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(propName) {
    if (this === map && propName === "one") {
        return false; // lie
    }
    return originalHasOwnProperty.call(this, propName);
};

Object.hasOwn = function(obj, propName) {
    if (obj === map && propName === "one") {
        return false; // lie
    }
    return originalHasOwn.call(Object, obj, propName);
};

console.log(
    "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call:", 
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, "one")
);
if (Object.hasOwn) {
    console.log("Object.hasOwn:", Object.hasOwn(map, "one"));
} else {
    console.log("Object.hasOwn not supported in this environment yet");
}
```

Detecting modifications of the original methods can be complex, so if you decide to try to do that, look for well-researched solutions with solid-looking citations. Normally, though, it's overkill. I note it here just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`

```
const map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.apply(map,[ "one"]));
```

or `call`

```
const map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(map,"one"));
```

or `bind`

```
const map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.bind(map)('one'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion **:** `hasOwnProperty` is really a bad property name.

But still if you want to work with it. There are few ways to achieve this **:**

- By using [Object.hasOwn()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

  ```js
  let map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};

  console.log(Object.hasOwn(map, "one")); // true
  ```
- By using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call()`

  ```js
  let map = {one: true, two: true, hasOwnProperty: true};

  console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, "one")); // true
  ```