# Does Object.keys(anObject) return anObject's prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, prototype

I'm reading [Eloquent JavaScript's Map section](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) and I'm having trouble understanding its last paragraph:

> If you do have a plain object that you need to treat as a map for some reason, it is useful to know that `Object.keys` returns only an object’s own keys, not those in the prototype. As an alternative to the `in` operator, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method, which ignores the object’s prototype.

I then assume that `Object.keys` does not return the properties and methods an object gets from the inheritance of its prototype. So I tried the following:

```
var anObject = {};
console.log(Object.keys(anObject)); //Array []
console.log("toString" in Object.keys(anObject)); //true
console.log(anObject.hasOwnProperty("toString")); //false
```

Apparently, `toString` is in the array returned by `Object.keys(anObject)`, but an empty array is returned when I logged its keys? Did I understand the passage wrongly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You understood the passage correctly, the usage of `in` here is wrong though.

It returns true, since the Array that `Object.keys(anObject)` returns has a property called `toString` in it's prototype. `in` also checks the prototype, while `hasOwnProperty` only checks the properties an Object actually has (meaning the properties that were "manually added" to the empty Object).

But it doesn't have an "own property" with the name `toString`

```js
let anObject = {};
let keys = Object.keys(anObject);

console.log("toString" in keys); //true, since there is a property "toString" in the keys.prototype object
console.log(keys.hasOwnProperty("toString")); //false, since there aren't any properties in the object itself
```

Comment: I see, so that's why. However, the passage says that 'As an alternative to `in` operator, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method...'. Since it says `hasOwnProperty` is an alternative method, how do I get the `false` result using `in` operator?

Comment: It says it in the few words after that "*which ignores the object’s prototype.*" indicating, that `in` doesn't ignore the object's prototype.

Comment: I see! The word 'alternative' misled me into thinking that both choices are viable, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`Object.keys(anObject)` returns an array, and `toString` is a valid method on arrays.

Since `in` checks for a property in the object, and in its prototype chain, the expression `"toString" in Object.keys(anObject)` returns `true`.

But this doesn't mean that `toString` is an owned property of `anObject`. That's why `anObject.hasOwnProperty("toString")` returns `false`.

Comment: I see! I understand what I got wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

> The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or **its prototype chain**.

As we all know, arrays are special types of object in Javascript with methods/properties like forEach(), length, map(), **toString()**, sort() and more. These aforementioned methods are present in the prototype of the array and not in the array itself. Whereas, `hasOwnProperty` only checks the properties the Object actually has and not in its prototype. Read more about the `in` operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). Also, use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)` instead of `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`. Read *Why?* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017693/why-use-object-prototype-hasownproperty-callmyobj-prop-instead-of-myobj-hasow).

Comment: I see! Thank you for your answer, I have also read from MDN, but I was probably mostly confused with the word 'alternative' as I thought that both `in` and `hasOwnProperty` are viable choices.