# The same function called twice with different parameters but only last is executed

Tags: javascript

I have 2 divs witch I need to animate:

```
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="p"></div>
```

Width of first div should become 70% and width of second div should become 30%. But when I'am trying to animate one div after another, calling at first function for 70% and then function for 30%, width of both of them become 30%.

Javascript code:

```
Anim({
    target: document.getElementsByClassName('d')[0],
    drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
        element.style.width = (progress * 70) + '%';
    }
});

Anim({
    target: document.getElementsByClassName('p')[0],
    drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
        element.style.width = (progress * 30) + '%';
    }
});
```

I don't understand why this is happening and how to make both functions work correctly.

Code snippet if needed:

```js
(() => {
  "use strict";

  const init = (params) => {
    const start = performance.now();
    const element = params.target || null;

    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
      let timeFraction = (time - start) / params.duration;

      if (timeFraction > 1) {
        timeFraction = 1;
      }

      const progress = params.timingFunc(timeFraction, params.timingArg);

      params.drawFunc(progress, element);

      if (timeFraction < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

      if (params.callback) {
        if (timeFraction >= 1) {
          params.callback();
        }
      }
    });
  };
  const timingFunctions = {
    linear: (timeFraction) => {
      return timeFraction;
    }
  };
  const paces = {
    easeIn: (func) => {
      return timingFunctions[func];
    }
  };
  const defaultParams = {
    duration: 1000,
    timingFunc: paces.easeIn('linear'),
    timingArg: null,
    delay: null,
    callback: null
  };
  const makeParams = (def, add) => {
    let params = def;

    if (add) {
      for (let i in add) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(add, i)) {
          params[i] = add[i];
        }
      }
    }

    return params;
  };

  function Anim(paramArgs) {
    const params = makeParams(defaultParams, paramArgs);

    if ('timingFunc' in paramArgs) {
      params.timingFunc = (typeof paramArgs.timingFunc === 'function') ? paramArgs.timingFunc : paces[paramArgs.timingFunc.pace](paramArgs.timingFunc.func);
    }

    if (!params.delay) {
      init(params);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        init(params);
      }, params.delay);
    }
  }

  window.Anim = Anim;
})();

Anim({
  target: document.getElementsByClassName('d')[0],
  drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
    element.style.width = (progress * 70) + '%';
  }
});

Anim({
  target: document.getElementsByClassName('p')[0],
  drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
    element.style.width = (progress * 30) + '%';
  }
});
```

```css
.d, .p {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="p"></div>
```

Comment: `console.log("p1:"+progress);` will give you the answer ;)

Comment: `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(add, i)) {` what happens here? is the `hasOwnProperty` method called here? why not simply use is directly?

Comment: @messerbill Yes, the hasOwnProperty method called here. I need IE8 support and direct use doesn't work there.

Comment: :'D The good old IE.....That was clear....If you see some kind of weird looking code think about it.....hm, must be an IE fix :D Tell your customer it's really time to upgrade their browsers

Comment: @messerbill this link show very good explanation why I wrote Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call instead of direct use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017693/why-use-object-prototype-hasownproperty-callmyobj-prop-instead-of-myobj-hasow

Comment: `I need IE8 support`  I assume you must be transpiling then, as `let` & `const` don't work with IE8..  `Object.assign` isn't going to work either, without a polyfill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that both `Anim` calls have the same `params` object. Both `params` objects have the same exact callback `drawFunc`.

**Why?** Because in `makeParams` you are doing this:

```
let params = def;
```

Then you assign to `params` which in turn alters the original `defaultParams` (aliased here as `def`). When the second function calls `Anim`, the callback `drawFunc` of this second call gets assigned to the `defaultParams` object. Since all `params` objects are basically a reference to `defaultParams`, they get altered too, and the callback of the last call to `Anim` gets assigned to all of them.

**To fix this,** just clone `def` using `Object.assign`:

```
let params = Object.assign({}, def);
```

**Side note:** The `target` property is also altered in the `params` object, but before it changes, it gets assigned to a new variable inside `init`:

```
const element = params.target || null;
```

Thus, even though it changes in the `params` object, you don't really notice because all subsequent code uses the variable `element` instead of `params.target`.

**Working code:**

```js
(() => {
  "use strict";

  const init = (params) => {
    const start = performance.now();
    const element = params.target || null;

    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
      let timeFraction = (time - start) / params.duration;

      if (timeFraction > 1) {
        timeFraction = 1;
      }

      const progress = params.timingFunc(timeFraction, params.timingArg);

      params.drawFunc(progress, element);

      if (timeFraction < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

      if (params.callback) {
        if (timeFraction >= 1) {
          params.callback();
        }
      }
    });
  };
  const timingFunctions = {
    linear: (timeFraction) => {
      return timeFraction;
    }
  };
  const paces = {
    easeIn: (func) => {
      return timingFunctions[func];
    }
  };
  const defaultParams = {
    duration: 1000,
    timingFunc: paces.easeIn('linear'),
    timingArg: null,
    delay: null,
    callback: null
  };
  const makeParams = (def, add) => {
    let params = Object.assign({}, def);

    if (add) {
      for (let i in add) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(add, i)) {
          params[i] = add[i];
        }
      }
    }

    return params;
  };

  function Anim(paramArgs) {
    const params = makeParams(defaultParams, paramArgs);

    if ('timingFunc' in paramArgs) {
      params.timingFunc = (typeof paramArgs.timingFunc === 'function') ? paramArgs.timingFunc : paces[paramArgs.timingFunc.pace](paramArgs.timingFunc.func);
    }

    if (!params.delay) {
      init(params);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        init(params);
      }, params.delay);
    }
  }

  window.Anim = Anim;
})();

Anim({
  target: document.getElementsByClassName('d')[0],
  drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
    element.style.width = (progress * 70) + '%';
  }
});

Anim({
  target: document.getElementsByClassName('p')[0],
  drawFunc: (progress, element) => {
    element.style.width = (progress * 30) + '%';
  }
});
```

```css
.d, .p {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="p"></div>
```

**Related issue:** [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/9867451)

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day.

Comment: @alexDev One little note, use `Object.assign` instead of `Object.create`, I'm have a headache so my thinking isn't clear, sorry! Check out the updated answer! `Object.create`, although works, is suitable for prototypal inheritance not cloning.