# Why does Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Number, "toString") return false?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12017703/14731 imply that:

- `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar")` is equivalent to (and safer than) `foo.hasOwnProperty("bar")`

However when running Chrome 75.0.3770.142 I see:

- `Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty("toString") // true`
- `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Number, "toString") // false`

Questions:

1. Shouldn't these return the same value?
2. Where should I be using in this case assuming I am dealing with dynamic types that may or may not be equal to built-in?

Comment: Uh, you're checking the `Number` *prototype* first, and then just `Number`. `Number !== Number.prototype`

Comment: @VLAZ Are you saying that I should be invoking `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Number.prototype, "toString")` instead?

Comment: Yes, because you are currently doing (essentially) `Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty` vs `Number.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @VLAZ Good catch, thank you. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually checking two different things:

- `Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty("toString")` will check if the *prototype* of the `Number` object contains the `toString` property and it doesn't come from its prototype chain (has**Own**Property).
- `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Number, "toString")` is essentially the same as `Number.hasOwnProperty("toString")` - it's *not* checking the prototype but the `Number` object itself.

These are two different objects as can be seen here:

```js
console.log(Number === Number.prototype)
```

So, the *prototype* is what contains the `toString` property and `Number` inherits it through that. So, in order to have equivalent check you need to check the prototype:

```js
console.log(Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty("toString")); // = true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Number.prototype, "toString")); // = true

console.log(Number.hasOwnProperty("toString")); // = false - not on this object...
console.log("toString" in Number); // = true - ...so it it's inherited
```