# Practical differences of Object.hasOwnProperty vs Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

**CLARIFICATION to moderator**
As some moderators are a whee bit quick when scanning questions, I have to underline that I am not asking why to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` instead of `myObject.hasOwnProperty`. The devil is in the details.

The [ESLint rule `no-prototype-builtins`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) forbids the use of built-ins coming from the `Object` prototype. It's there to provide you against code such as this:

```js
function serverMethodToParseClientInput(json){
  const o = JSON.parse(json);
  if (o.hasOwnProperty("foo")) {
    doSomethingMeaningful();
  }
}


const stringFromClient = "{\"hasOwnProperty\":1, \"reason\": \"Crash your system\"}";

serverMethodToParseClientInput(stringFromClient);
```

Trying to call the method on objects created with `null` as their prototype will also fail, which I think is an even more reasonable thing to guard against. Example: `const o = Object.create(null);`.

Instead of `obj.hasOwnProperty(field)`, you are supposed to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, field)`. I don't really see the difference between this and `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, field)`. Granted, `Object` is not its own prototype, so there is a difference of sorts, but since you can overwrite the props on either object, there isn't really much of a safeguard here, IMHO.

So I'm wondering if there is any point in reaching for the prototype of `Object` when `Object` will do?

Comment: `Object.hasOwnProperty` is really weird - you're referring to the `hasOwnPrototype` method on `Object.protoype`, and it only happens to work because *everything* inherits from `Object.prototype`, including constructors. You can still use it, assuming nothing has assigned to `Object.hasOwnProperty`, but it's quite confusing

Comment: @adiga This is not a duplicate. Your linked question just gives the same answers I already have in my question. Please re-read. I don't wonder why I should use the method on the prototype. I wonder why I can't just use `Object.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Using `Object.hasOwnProperty` makes it look like a static method like `assign`. It can be confusing. It will work because `Object.hasOwnProperty === Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. It is similar to using, say `({}).hasOwnProperty.call`

Comment: OK, both of those comments are sufficient answers to me (feel free to actually post an answer). So it's basically about coding style; trying to avoid confusing/ambigous constructs.

Comment: Note that, it looks inside `Function.prototype` object before falling back to `Object.prototype`. If you override `Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty = () => 'custom'`, it will take that implementation

Comment: I'd usually store `const hop = ({}).hasOwnProperty;` and use it as `hop.call(obj, key)`. To me, this is the best approach; makes it clear what the intent is and where the method is coming from and is shorter than `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call()`

Comment: Honestly, Thomas, if you want clear intent, you extract it into something like `has(obj, field)` :-) https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Object.hasOwnProperty` is weird because it makes it seem like you are using a static method like `Object.assign()`.

It still works because if a property is not found on `Object`, it falls back to `Function.prototype` object. And, this object inherits from `Object.prototype`. So, if you have a custom implementation for `Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, then `Object.hasOwnProperty` will use that implementation instead of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`

```js
console.log( Object.hasOwnProperty === Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty ) // true
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype ) // true
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype ) // true

Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty = _ => 'custom implementaion in Function.prototype'

const obj = { prop: 10 }

console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'prop')) // custom implementaion
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'prop')) // true
```

Note: The difference between `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, prop)` and `myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017693)

Comment: See, that's exactly the thing I was pondering. The `Function` reference was a good gotcha to know about.