# How to implement vue-guards beforeEach properly to for authentication

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Why my code directly goes to my else statement even though I followed the documentation in vue-router?

It directly goes to my else statement "Not even a match". It should print "Found a match".

Did I miss something here?

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: () => import("../views/vLogin.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Article",
    component: () => import("@/views/articles/vArticleManage"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    console.log("Found a match")
    let sampleAuth = true;
    if(sampleAuth) {
      next();
    } else{
      next({
       path: "/login",
        query: {
          redirect: to.fullPath
        }
      })
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Not even a match")
  }
})
export default router;
```

p.s 
Here is the image when I tried to log the "to"
[image]

Comment: `console.log(to)` to inspect the route info

Comment: Hi @Dan, I've updated the question with the image of "to"

Comment: Hi, it shows you are accessing the `login` route which nas no `requiresAuth` meta property

Comment: Oh okay, maybe I miss something in my code.

Comment: Since your `login` route doesn't have the `requiredAuth` property, it will not match.  You would have to add it like you did on the `/` route.  But you probably don't want that, since the login shouldn't require auth.  Seems like it's working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too initially followed that suggestion from the documentation and had no success with it.

Instead I now use `router.beforeResolve((to, from, next)` which fires much later (fires the latest) in the logic.

`beforeEach` fires very early where I found it result in a much higher chance of creating code execution race condition issues in navigation guards as if something has not had time to initialize or not had chance to set an expected state.

There is also `router.beforeEnter` that fires a little before `beforeResolve` but way later than `beforeEach`.

I have 5 major VUE projects, so far am not sure what the actual use of `beforeEach` is since anything I have tried has not worked with it.

> Hint: I always `return void` after calling `next()` to ensure further logic is not executed after and is much cleaner than `if/else` statements especially if there is a lot of `if` statements.

I am not sure about the usage of `to.matched.some` as everything I have built is predictable exact match so I actually use:

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(to.meta, 'requiresAuth')`

```js
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(to.meta, 'requiresAuth')) {

    console.log("Found a match")

    let sampleAuth = true;

    if(sampleAuth) {

      next();
      return;

    }

    next({
      name: 'login', // <-- Login route has a name, use that reference instead.
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath
      }
    })

    return;

  }

  console.log("Not even a match")

})
```

> Hint: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(...)` while ugly, is more secure and reliable than `myVar.hasOwnProperty(...)` [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017693/why-use-object-prototype-hasownproperty-callmyobj-prop-instead-of-myobj-hasow)