# What keys are unsafe to assign on a JavaScript object (e.g. '__proto__')?

Tags: javascript, security

I want to use a JavaScript object (`{}`) as a dictionary to store untrusted data. (I know there's [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but let's say I don't want to use `Map`.)

If I write

```js
let obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
```

where `key` and `value` are supplied by an unstrusted source, what keys can cause surprising behavior?

I know that assigning `obj.__proto__` can change the object's prototype and therefore change the behavior of the object. (This is sometimes called [prototype poisoning](https://medium.com/intrinsic/javascript-prototype-poisoning-vulnerabilities-in-the-wild-7bc15347c96).) So I should probably exclude `'__proto__'`:

```js
let obj = {};
if (key !== '__proto__') {
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

Are there other such unsafe keys that can change an object's behavior in some way, or is `'__proto__'` the only one?

Bonus points if you cite the ECMAScript spec or a reference document.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `Map` (for some reason), at least use `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the properties on `Object.prototype` can cause problematic name collisions:

```js
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)
);
```

That's it.

Another option to avoid having to worry about name collisions is to make an object which *doesn't* inherit from `Object.prototype`, eg:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null);

// Now, this is perfectly fine (though weird):
obj.__proto__ = 'foo';
console.log(obj.__proto__);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're simply looking for excluding extant values from the prototype you can use a combination of two checks:

1) Is the property they are trying to set already present in the object:

```
const exists = '__proto__' in obj; // Or whichever property name they are setting
```

2) And if so, is it direct property, or does it come from upstream (e.g. you may allow them to set/overwrite existing properties they have previous set directly on the object).

```
const onSelf = obj.hasOwnProperty('__proto__'); // Or whichever property name they are setting
```

Then maybe your protection would look like:

```
if (!(key in obj) || obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: what if i create an own property named "hasOwnProperty" ? facepalm. `{hasOwnProperty:Boolean}`

Comment: [Why use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, prop)` instead of `myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12017693/1048572)