# Recursive hasOwnProperty for objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, hasownproperty

I have an object as:

```
const object = {};
object.property1 = 54;
object.property1.property1 = 60;
```

now I would like to achieve something like this:

```
if(object.hasOwnProperty('property1')){
//do something
}
else if(object.hasOwnProperty('property1').hasOwnProperty('property1')){
//do something
}
else{
//do something
}
```

But it fails at the `else if` part.
why can't we use `hasOwnProperty` recursively? what is the workaround? I am stuck at this for many hours now.

I have tried to use:

```
if(object.property1.property1){
//do something
}
```

but this gives me `undefined`

So how to get around this situation? Please help!

Comment: you are chaining hasOwnProperty that returns a boolean

Comment: `false.hasOwnProperty()` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Is there any work around for this? the thing that I want to achieve?

Comment: The value of `object.property1` is a number. Numbers cannot have properties.

Comment: Use an actual recursion

Comment: yeah I get it but is there any other method that we can use to check if the property1 exists in the property1 of the json object?

Comment: `object.property1.hasOwnProperty("name")` will be `true` if the value of `object.property1` has a property called "name".

Comment: what do you mean by `//do something` ? assign a value ? or are you expecting a kind of super switch ? your question is unclear...

Comment: @MisterJojo I am trying to assigning a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a recursive function

```js
const object = {};
object.property1 = {};
object.property1.property2 = 60;

if (hasOwnPropertyRecursive(object, 'property2')) {
  console.log('yes')
} else {
  console.log('no')
}

function hasOwnPropertyRecursive(obj, prop) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return true
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).some(key => hasOwnPropertyRecursive(obj[key], prop))
}
```

Comment: will using `hasOwn` be more helpful or is `hasOwnProperty` good in this case?

Comment: Use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)` instead in case the object has [done something weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017693/why-use-object-prototype-hasownproperty-callmyobj-prop-instead-of-myobj-hasow) with its `hasOwnProperty` method.

Answer (score 0):

> @MisterJojo I am trying to assigning a value

so you may do that this way...

```js
const 
  objA = {}
, objB = { propX: 'b' } 
, objC = { propX: { propX: 'c' } }
  ;
setLastProp( objA, 'propX', 'x_A' );
setLastProp( objB, 'propX', 'x_B' );
setLastProp( objC, 'propX', 'x_C' );

console.log( 'objA ->', JSON.stringify( objA ));
console.log( 'objB ->', JSON.stringify( objB ));
console.log( 'objC ->', JSON.stringify( objC ));



function setLastProp  ( obj, propName, value )
  {
  let next = obj, prev = obj, count = 0;
  while (next.hasOwnProperty(propName)) 
    {  
    prev = next;
    next = next[propName];
    };
  prev[propName] = value;
  }
```