# In Javascript, why Object.getPrototypeOf(person) works but person.getPrototypeOf(person) won't?

Tags: javascript, prototype

For the following code, I wonder why `Object.getPrototypeOf(person)` works, but `person.getPrototypeOf(person)` won't work?  I thought the rule is: if the object doesn't have such property or method, it will go up the prototype chain to try and get it, and call it on `this` (such as `Animal.getName.call(this)` where `this` is the context of the `woofie` object).  So in that case, `person.getPrototypeOf(person)` should become `Object.getPrototypeOf.call(person, person)` and should work too?

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var person = new Person("Ang Lee")

console.log("the prototype of person is", Object.getPrototypeOf(person));
```

---

**Update:** for the answers that say `getPrototypeOf` is a static method, does that mean:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.foo = function() { ... }
}

Person.bar = function() { ... }
```

that `foo` is "in the chain", and callable by any inherited objects, while `bar` is not, and `bar` is like `getPrototypeOf`, which is a static method?

Comment: Note that `typeof Object == 'function'`

Comment: It's a static method of `Object`, and can therefore not be invoked on `Object` instances.

Comment: See also [Why were ES5 Object methods not added to Object.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9735026/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

`Object.getPrototypeOf` is a property of the `Object` *type* itself, and not of the `prototype` of `Object`.

Because it's not actually in the prototype chain, it won't be found when you call `person.getProtoTypeOf()`.

It's more akin to a "static method" as seen in other OO languages.

Comment: do you think what is in the update of the question is correct?  (is this the only way a static method is defined?)

Comment: Yes, what you've described in your update is more or less correct.  `Person.bar` is a static method, and `.foo` is an instance method.  However the way you've written it `foo` is **not** on the prototype chain, because it is only bound to each instance at creation time, rather than added to `Person.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

`.getPrototypeOf` is a function put on `Object`, not on it's prototype. You can look it up if you want:

```
"getPrototypeOf" in Object.prototype; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

If `getPrototypeOf` were a method contained in `Object.prototype`, it would also be available on objects of type `Person`, however, `getPrototypeOf` is attached to `Object`, which is only the constructor function of `Object` instances, not the prototype.

For some reason, the creators of Javascript decided that prototypes are attached to constructor functions and not vice versa; if they hadn't made such questionable decision, you would not have had to ask this question.

P.S. anybody interested in a more elegant/clean implementation of prototype based object inheritance can check out http://iolanguage.com/