# How to convert a javascript for loop to while loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following code

```
let branch_timings=locations.branch_timings;
for(let key of Object.keys(branch_timings)){
  branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled=false;
}

console.log(locations);
```

I tried converting this to while loop like this:

```
let keys=locations.keys()
let i=0;
while(i<keys.length)
{
    let key=keys[i];
    branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled=false;
    i++;
}

console.log(locations);
```

when I run my while loop code this is the error I get

```
TypeError: locations.keys is not a function
```

This is part of a bigger code from a question i posted earlier. Every solution I have found is in either `for` loop or `forEach` I am trying to learn how to convert these loops to while. I am fairly new to javascript, your opinions will be appreciated.

Comment: `let keys = Object.keys(branch_timings)`

Answer (score 1):

You need `Object.keys` to enumerate keys.

```js
let keys=Object.keys(locations);
let i=0;
while(i<keys.length)
{
    let key=keys[i];
    branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled=false;
    i++;
}

console.log(locations);
```

Comment: To expand on why this is correct vs. the OP's example, the answer lies in the fact that [`Object.keys()` is not a prototype method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017736/why-is-object-keys-method-not-added-to-object-prototype).

Answer (score 0):

Correct translation should be that.

```
let keys= Object.keys(locations.branch_timings);
let i=0;
while(i < keys.length)
{
    let key=keys[i];
    locations.branch_timings[key].timingsEnabled=false;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much, this worked! could you please explain to me why do we write Object.keys instead of locations.keys

Comment: @esqew explained that in his comment, keys() method is not part of object prototype, you have to use it from Object wrapper

Answer (score 0):

To use `locations.keys()` Make Sure your variable `location` is of type `Array`. The TypeError you're getting suggests the variable `location` is not an `Array`.

If it's an object, you should use `Object.keys(locations)`.