# Why javascript committee decided to introduce Object.entries instead of Object.prototype.entries?

Tags: javascript

I would highly appreciate if someone could enlighten me why javascript committee has chosen `Object.entries`, `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, over `Object.prototype.entries`. `Object.prototype.keys`, `Object.prototype.values`.

I am asking this question because it's for me unclear what was the motivation for choosing one implementation over another. For instance why an `Array` got those functions bind to a prototype whereas `Object` does not. 
I've tried to search through committee [specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.entries), but it did not found an answer.

Comment: Because an object should not be concerned with obtaining its own entries and other reflective API. This is about design. Going to find the source.

Comment: What if the object has it's own `entries` property which overwrites the old `entries`? You'd have to use `Object.prototype.entries.call(obj)`. Quite ugly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746215/1048572?

Comment: @Bergi yes! thanks for digging the source!

Comment: @Bergi that and https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es3-1-object-static-methods-rationale-document discussing other rationale for sandboxing.