# Why do some array methods rely on the global Array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'm going through the [MDN docs on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and when we want to test whether or not an object is an array we use `isArray()`. However, it's usage is very different to most of the other methods. When you use the regular syntax an error pops up:

```
console.log([1,2,3].isArray());  // TypeError: [1, 2, 3].isArray is not a function
```

Whereas this does work:

```
console.log(Array.isArray([1,2,3]))
```

I don't understand why `isArray()` (and a couple of other methods) rely upon some global object rather than just being accessible via the object in question. Why do some methods require the global array object?

Comment: Because `({}).isArray()` could never work, but `Array.isArray({})` will yield `false` as expected.

Comment: If `isArray` were an instance method, and you tried to call it on something that isn't an array, how do you expect it to have access to that method?

Comment: It's *not* an array method. You couldn't use it on non-arrays if it was.

Comment: A big thanks for all those fast answers. You all make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> rather than just being accessible via the object in question.

Because the whole purpose of `Array.isArray` is to be called on unknown objects. You don't know whether it's an array, you wouldn't know whether the method was accessible on it. The static method even works with values like `null`, which would inevitably throw an exception when you tried to invoke a method on them.

---

#### Digression:

`isArray` being callable as an instance method *can* work. In languages where everything is an object, like Smalltalk, Ruby or Io, even things like `nil` can have a `isNil` method. This approach has other problems of course, as with dynamic method dispatch every arbitrary object could overwrite the method and claim to be an array - on the other hand, that's exactly what we want for [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

We could even simulate this in JS using `Object.prototype.isArray = () => false;` and `Array.prototype.isArray = () => true;`. Apart from failing on `null` and `undefined`, it still wouldn't work with objects that don't inherit from (our realm's) `Object.prototype`. And JavaScript "properties" that mix data fields and methods don't help either (consider the object parsed from the JSON string `{"isArray":"maybe"}`). We would always have to expect an exception from either `.isArray` not being a function, or from it being overwritten with a method that throws.
If we want to go for duck typing in JS, checking whether an object has an integer `.length` property is usually the way to go. Or more advanced, trying to follow the [symbol-based iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). (That's what `Array.from` uses, for example).

---

But since arrays are a bit special in JS (with their magic `.length` property), we want a built-in reliable way to detect them, and that's what `Array.isArray` does.

Regarding other static `Array` methods: `Array.of` is pretty obvious, it's a factory function (like a constructor) and it can't be an instance method because there is no instance to work with in the first place. For `Array.from` the situation is a bit more like with `isArray`, a duck-typing `Object.prototype.toArray` approach could have worked as well but was dismissed for practical and design reasons.

See also [Why were ES5 Object methods not added to Object.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9735026/1048572), [Why use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, prop) instead of myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12017693/1048572) and [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty() (for objects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13239317/1048572) for similar discussions.

Comment: Your answer makes way more sense than your comment

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good that one can't downvote comments, then? (Though I don't see what's wrong with it)

Comment: I thought the comment made perfect sense for the record

Answer (score 2):

.isArray() is a *static* method, it exists on the Array "class" but not on each particular instance. Static methods are called like this: Array.isArray(). Object.create() is another example.

Methods like `.map` or `.slice` are not static, so they exist on each instance of the Array "class".

Comment: Simple and understanding. Thanks boris

Answer (score 1):

`Array` (denoted with a captial "A") indicates the JavaScript native `Array` object. `[...]` represents an instance of an array. As with many languages, some properties/methods are static. That is, they don't exist on instances only the type. This is often done when the value of the property or behavior of the method doesn't vary from instance to instance, so there's no need for it to be "instance-specific". Figuring out if something is an array, doesn't change from instance to instance (and frankly, doesn't make a lot of sense to ask an array instance if it is an instance of an Array).

Comment: @DaniloGasques Please don't ever edit someone's answer in the way you attempted to do here. Edits are for corrections to typos, not to change what the answer says.