# Array.from instead of Array.prototype.from

Tags: javascript

As far as I have seen any array related method it has to be accessed from its prototype, e.g. `Array.prototype.slice`.

Why is the `from` method called on `Array` object as in `Array.from` instead of being called as `Array.prototype.from`?

Comment: Why would make sense to *have an array instance* in order to *create a new array*?

Comment: `slice` is used on an existing array while `from` creates a new one.

Comment: `Array.from('foo')` works fine, whereas `'foo'.from()` would fail because `'foo'` isn't an instance of Array.

Comment: [Static method instead of Prototype method Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67624051)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at `Array.from` as a constructor for arrays. The important thing here is that it can create an array from both array-like structures (having array-like properties like *indexes* and `.length`) and also iterables (objects with `.next()` or in other words - having a registered iterator).

There is absolutely no point in having the `.from()` method attached to the prototype like `[1, 2, 3].from()`. What do you expect this method to do exactly in this context? It serves no purpose.

In general, the instance (prototype) methods manipulate a specific **already existing instance** of an array. Static ones like `Array.from()`, `Array.of()` and `Array.isArray()` don't (and shouldn't) require an instance.

This is true not only for arrays but for general class/prototype design especially in data-structures.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the `Array.prototype` because `Array` instances do not benefit from this method (it does not use any context). As to why it is on the constructor, that's purely convention. You could have the function floating around in the global scope e.g. `ArrayFrom()` but the specification groups related functions under their respective constructor as a convention and as sort of a namespace to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Array.from is a static method that returns array, Array.prototype.slice is a method from the Array prototype and can be called on Arrays.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is that JavaScript uses prototype chain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

In general, when the method is not found in the instance, it looks into the prototype. If the method is not even there, it looks in the following prototype in the chain and so on. So this is why `slice` is found even if it is defined in the prototype.

The second reason is that the prototype is shared by all the instances of that class. So all the arrays share the same prototype - same object. Therefore the method doesn't need to be repeated in every instance and we save some space.

`from()`, on the other hand, is class method - you don't need instance to call that method. It is therefore defined directly on the Array class rather than on the prototype (because then it would be instance method).