# Should I worry about conflicts with possible future ECMAScript changes if I want to add a generically named property to a Function object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function which can be invoked through the following ways:

```
log() 
log.error()
```

Based on my understanding, we can creating such a function by writing on the function itself:

```js
function log(){

}
log.error = () => {}
```

Is it not recommended writing on the function this way? Because JavaScript might release an update in the future which might hold the "error" property, then my "error" property will be overriding that JavaScript feature.

---

Here's an example of where people might be using this pattern and why it's useful.

For example, Jquery:

```js
$( "#button-container button" ).on( "click", function( event ) {} )
```

and

```js
$.ajax({  url: "/api/getWeather" });
```

you see this pattern in many popular libraries.

the `$` is an object,

it's callable, so you can invoke it `$('css query selector here')`
and it's chainable, so you can call other methods on it `$().on()`, and it has methods on it `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line of thinking is well-intentioned, but doesn't scale. Take for instance

- `Object.prototype`. If we applied this line of thinking everywhere, we'd have to apply it to `Object.prototype`. Every object by default has `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain, unless you [`Object.create(null, {...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Do people worry every day that every single property with a generic name that they set on an object could one day overwrite a future standard property? Not that I know of.
- Or something less dramatic and more realistic: static properties. classes in JS are basically syntactic sugar over constructor *functions* and prototypes. When you use static properties, you're defining something on a function object- the constructor function for the class. Do you also worry about name conflicts whenever you do that? (probably not)

You worry about your own choices clashing with future changes to the standard, but you should think about the other way around too: The ECMAScript standards committee wouldn't want to make a change that breaks the web (all the websites on the web that use JavaScript and have been making naming decisions for the past how many years of its existence). Go google "JavaScript smoosh" and read about the `array.prototype.flatten` fiasco.

A common phrase/rule in [TC39](https://tc39.es/) ([ECMA-International's ECMAScript standards committee](https://www.ecma-international.org/technical-committees/tc39/)) is [**"don't break the web"**](https://github.com/tc39/how-we-work/blob/main/terminology.md#web-compatibilitydont-break-the-web):

> A change to JavaScript is considered "**web compatible**" if it preserves the current behavior of existing websites. If it changes the behavior of existing websites, it's considered to "**break the web**".
>
> The definition here is a bit fuzzy and empirical--it's always possible to construct a website which will break under any particular change or addition to JavaScript, and the key is how common the broken websites are. If too many websites break, then web browsers will refuse to ship the change.
>
> **"Don't break the web"** is a shared goal of [TC39](https://tc39.es/) and all web standards bodies: We aim to preserve web compatibility as we evolve the language. Even if a change would be convenient for developers, it's not worth it if we hurt lots of users in the process!
>
> **Example**
>
> There was an effort to add a method `Array.prototype.contains`. However, this broke many websites ([reference](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible)). As a result, the method was named as [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/) instead.

In the end, the decision of what you do is up to you. Because of "don't break the web", I think in general, you can rest easier when choosing to do things like this.

Here's what I wouldn't generalize this way of thinking to: prototypes of standard classes. If you're just adding properties to object *instances* at the child-most-end of prototype chains (such as instances of `Function`) and not to *prototypes* of standard classes (such as the prototype of `Function` instances), then it's not too big of a deal, but when it comes to adding things to standard prototypes, I *personally* wouldn't go about doing things like this all the time- only when I see that it would increase readability significantly and over a large part of my codebase.

#### Self-defense techniques

- Follow proposals to the ECMAScript standard to see if such conflict-inducing changes are planned or being discussed,
- Do a runtime check to see if the `Function` prototype chain includes an `error` property in it, and emit an warning message in the console if so (but don't throw an exception- then your site would break! Just log a warning and keep chugging along). And have a plan for what to do if such a conflict occurs in the future.
- Choose an alternate design making a compromise between your ideal and what you think is likely to avoid future problems- ex- choosing a naming scheme that is unlikely to have conflicts with new additions to the ECMAScript standard.
- If you actually only care about being defensive and not about ergonomics, you can take different approaches like not using property method functions at all (and instead use free functions like "`function myError(func) {/*...*/}`"), or use [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) instead.

#### Misc

Since you expressed curiosity in what JQuery is doing, based on what you have in your question post: `typeof $` gives `"function"`, `Object.getPrototypeOf($).constructor === Function` is `true`, and `typeof $.ajax` gives `"function"`. As far as I know, what you have proposed is currently the only way to achieving *exactly* what you have described that you want in your question post.

Any time you want to fiddle with something that has to do with changing how an object or a class of objects behaves with respect to "lower-level" JS behaviour, your first instinct should be to see if there's [a standard `Symbol` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) for it, such as [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive), , [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), and [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species). I am not aware of such a symbol property existing for turning any object into a callable object. I.e. to make something callable, you currently *have* have a `Function` in its prototype chain.

To answer a follow-up question you posed in the comments:

> can we think about achieving the same using classes? or do you think they're useless regarding this scenario?

This sounds like you are proposing a more specific case of Symbol properties (on a class (in its prototype) instead of any object). So by extension, the answer is no, I don't think they're useful here.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it not recommended writing on the function this way?

No, it's fine. It is an established practice and used by many libraries, as you noted. It is very common to put properties right on function objects, and heck, `class`es even have dedicated syntax for adding `static` properties to them.

You're right of course that in theory there is a potential for conflict - however it is really small. Iff the language were to be extended by adding a new `Function.prototype` method, and iff you were using a third-party library (out of your control) that did use and rely on this new method, then you could not pass your `log` function with its overwritten property into that library. This is unlikely to be an issue though, and it could trivially be fixed by using `something(x => log(x))` instead of `something(log)`.

A name clash is even more unlikely since the names of your custom static methods will have to do with logging, not with functions, as new `Function.prototype` methods would. Only if you were extending the `Function` capabilities with more function-methods, say `.partialApply`, `.curry`, `.fixArity` or something, *then* it would be a bad idea since they have a higher potential for collisions.

Also it's rather unlikely that new `Function.prototype` methods get added to the language at all. While I only know of [an official policy not to add new methods to `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9735026/1048572), the case for `Function.prototype` would be quite similar - the TC39 knows about the customary ways to add arbitrary static properties to functions and would [prevent additions that are likely to break the web](https://github.com/tc39/how-we-work/blob/main/terminology.md#web-compatibilitydont-break-the-web) or cause incompatibilities further down the road. And the push is actually in the opposite direction: new proposals like the [bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator), [call-this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-call-this) or the [pipe operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) actually add more syntax for different ways to call a function without having to use any of their methods.

So in conclusion: **No, you should not worry**.